# Run eclipse project as root without running eclipse as root

Tags: 12.04, sudo, eclipse

How can one execute eclipse project as root without running eclipse as root?

I'm writing a C++ program that uses Opencv and Boost libraries. When trying to execute the program, I get the following error:

> bind: Permission denied

I've read that running eclipse as root is not a good idea, to say the least.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you're reading is right: running anything as root that doesn't (or shouldn't) need root gives is a bad idea. Instead, I would check to see if the path to the application is correct.